spring-data-mongodb v3.4.18 with mongodb-driver-sync v4.6.1 slow insertDocument() performance on MongoDB V-5.0 server
I have Spring v-5.3.36 with backend MongoDB server v5.0. The problem is that if I use spring-data-mongodb v3.4.18 with mongodb-driver-sync v4.6.1 driver combination, the MongoRepository.insert(doc) call is very slow under the load with below behavior:
(1) Even with MongoClientSettings.applyToConnectionPoolSettings(builder ->builder.maxSize(1000)), the actual connection pool size observed on MongoDB server never exceeded 70.
(2) Turned on debug log, saw bunch of "Closing connection connectionId" calls
2024-06-14 14:54:30.366 [pool-14859-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insertDocument - Inserting Document containing fields: [_id, ... sessionId, actionHost, _class] in collection: collection_xyz**
2024-06-14 14:54:33.163 [pool-14859-thread-1] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.connection.debug - Closing connection connectionId{localValue:406}
2024-06-14 14:54:33.164 [pool-14859-thread-1] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.operation.debug - retryWrites set to true but the server is a standalone server.
2024-06-14 14:54:33.164 [pool-14859-thread-1] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command.debug - Sending command '{"insert": ...}, "documents": [{"_id":...}]}' with request id 15074 to database my_db on connection [connectionId{localValue:390, serverValue:95}] to server localhost:27017
2024-06-14 14:54:33.169 [pool-14859-thread-1] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command.debug - Execution of command with request id 15074 completed successfully in 4.30 ms on connection [connectionId{localValue:390, serverValue:95}] to server localhost:27017**
(3) Slow performance. Notice in above log there is 3s difference between MongoTemplate.insertDocument() call and mongodb driver actually save it to DB

However if I switched to spring-data-mongodb v3.2.12 with mongodb-driver-sync v4.2.3 driver combination(suppose to be for MongoDB server v4.4), the MongoRepository.insert(doc) call is very fast without any other code change:
(1) The actual connection pool size observed on MongoDB server consistently at ~350
(2) No "Closing connection connectionId" calls observed when debug logging is turned on.
(3) Fast performance: only milli-second difference between MongoTemplate.insertDocument() and mongodb driver is triggered.
So it looks like to me that spring-data-mongodb v3.4.18 is choking off on calling mongodb driver with long gapping time between MongoTemplate.insertDocument() and triggering MongoDB driver. This caused significant slow down. Any idea why this is happening?
Note,
Database server itself performed very well and any slowness observed regardless whey driver version is used.
I also tried increasing JVM heap size and no effect. Also increased connection idle time setting and the problem remained.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Maybe this example will help:
Given a workload of 10 threads inserting total 30K new records into a collection, with same MongoDB-v5.0 server, same code/connection pool setting, same hardware:
(1) If using spring-data-mongodb v3.4.18/mongodb-driver-sync v4.6.1 driver set, there are 16K inserts taking longer than 100ms
(2) If using spring-data-mongodb v3.2.12/mongodb-driver-sync v4.2.3 driver set, there are ONLY 500 inserts taking longer than 100ms.
Question,
Why driver set spring-data-mongodb v3.4.18/mongodb-driver-sync v4.6.1 is so much slower?
